# Load content of an external page to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my main page

```
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
  #exp{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background:#00FF00;
  }

  </style>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
  $("#exp").load('aboutus.html');

  })
  </script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="exp">

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to load this content from the page aboutus.html
The content in that page is

```
<div style="height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px">Hai</div>
```

I tried load,get,.html etc But none of them are working.
I don't want to include php

Methods I tried

```
$("#exp").load('aboutus.html');
$("#exp").get('aboutus.html');
$("#exp").html(url(aboutus.html'));
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? If you look at the net tab are you getting a 404?

Comment: why not use an iframe?

Comment: are you getting any errors?? please check your console... and make sure the main page and aboutus.html is in same folder

Comment: Either the path to your jQuery file is incorrect, or the path to aboutus.html is !

Comment: @Omar `$(function(){` is `.ready`

Comment: Found a strange thing the code works in firefox,but not in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this by using AJAX call using jquery.

Just wrap up your about page into JSON call back function. For detail see below

**Main Page Code**

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
#exp {
height: 100%;
width:100%;
position: absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
background:#00FF00;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function(){
jQuery.getJSON('about.php?callback=?',function(data){
if(data.status == 'success') {
        jQuery('#exp').html(data.html);
    }
});
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="exp"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**About.PHP page**

```
<?php
$html .=<<<HTML
    <div style="height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px">Hai</div>
HTML;
$strippedHTML = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t"), ' ', $html);
echo $_GET['callback'] . '({"status":"success", "html":"' . addslashes(trim($strippedHTML)) . '"})';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of failure is the local test : if you open the main file using `file://` then the other file appears to be from another domain and the operation is prevented.

From [the .load documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) :

> Additional Notes:
>
> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

You must use a http server to test this page.

Other than that, and supposing you have the jquery.js file, your code works : [test it online](http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/load.html).